# How to setup two JMS connection factories in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

Is there a simple way to configure two message brokers in Spring Boot?

Spring Boot supports the ability to configure multiple datasources, so I would think the same convention could be used for connection factories.

```
spring.activemq.pooled=false
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://broker-a:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin

spring.activemq.broker-b.pooled=false
spring.activemq.broker-b.broker-url=tcp://broker-b:61616
spring.activemq.broker-b.user=admin
spring.activemq.broker-b.password=admin
```

Answer (score 0):

At least second one needs to be created and registered explicitly as Spring bean.

Comment: any exampleto provide?

Comment: https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/blob/9518ec1c93e960afe071505a33eea9d15a02ceb5/05-jms/0511-jms-caching-connection-factory/src/main/java/net/lkrnac/book/eiws/chapter05/text/JmsConfiguration.java